# Audio in Qt6 application does not work if run from cron of systemd

Tags: systemd, cron, audio, qt

Ubuntu 21.10, Qt 6.2.0.
In my QML I have a `MediaPlayer`:

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: mediaPlayer
    videoOutput: videoOutput
    audioOutput: audioOutput
    onErrorOccurred: { console.log(mediaPlayer.errorString) }
}

AudioOutput {
    id: audioOutput
    volume: 1.0
}

VideoOutput {
    id: videoOutput
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 1080
    height: 1920
}
```

When I execute my application from QtCreator or launching it from command line all works fine and I can hear the audio.
Instead when the application is launched by a `cron` job or by a `systemd` service, I have no errors but no audio as well.

Both the cron `job` or the `systemd` service run as a specified `user` NOT as `root`.

Comment: cron and systemd will not preserve the environment variables of your shell session. You might need to set them manually.

Comment: Good point, in my script I set the env var for my app only. Is there a way to restore (`source` something?) them? Or I have to dump them and insert them manually in my script?

Comment: I don't see any specific var related to the audio, though.

Comment: Could be something as simple as `$PATH` or the environment is completely unrelated. You could start by adding all of the output of `env`. If it now works, you can remove part of the variables until the application stops working. Repeat until you've found the set of necessary variables.

Comment: I'm going to do exactly what you said. I was just hoping to understand how it works instead of make random trials :)